# Solr index xml file with html tag (with DataImportHandler)

Tags: xml, solr, dataimporthandler

I have Solr 4.10.4 and I would like to index a xml file.
Somes xml tags contain html tags.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no' ?>
<root>
   <info>
        <text>
             <p>text 1</p>
             <p>text 2</p>
             <p>text 3</p> 
        </text> 
   </info> 
</root>
```

I used this :

```
<charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
```

but it does not work and I don't know what is wrong.

M.

Comment: **solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory** will going to strip the html tags from Indexed data not from the stored values. Do you want to convert the stored value as well?

Answer (score 0):

**HTMLStripCharFilterFactory** is going to strip the HTML tage from indexed data not from the stored.
To strip html tags while indexing you can use **HTMLStripTransformer** in dataimporthandler. Below is the sample DIH for the same.

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="fDS" type="FileDataSource" />
<document>
    <entity name="tika-test" processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
            url="${solr.install.dir}/example/exampledocs/content.xml" forEach="/root" dataSource="fDS">
            <field column="text" xpath="/root/info/text/p" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

There is one attribute for this transformer, stripHTML, which is a boolean value (true/false) to signal if the
HTMLStripTransformer should process the field or not.

Comment: What about the xpath ? xpath="/root/info/text" is correct ?

Comment: Yes xpath will be the same that you have mentioned.

Comment: When I execute a query from the web interface, the field is only filled with "\n" character.

Comment: why don't I have the content of the text xml tag ?

Comment: @Medley..Actually there was some problem in **xpath**.Correct **xpath**  will be "/root/info/text/p".Please refer to the answer that i gave as i did few changes. It will solve your problem.

Comment: It is better now. I also added this : flatten="true".

Comment: Do you know how to avoid errors when character & or < or > is present in the text tag ? Is there a filter for that ?